# Connecting UITableView cells back to the data source

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a paper based form with a number of different sections, with each section having a number of different questions. I am displaying this as a UITableView. Each question is displayed as a UITableViewCell with the question itself, and a UITextField for an answer. The UITableView is currently backed by two object types, Section and Question - with each Section object containing an array of Questions.

I'm wondering how I can easily connect any editing that occurs in the UITableView with the objects. For example, if the user types in an answer to question 1, I'd like to then be able to assign that answer text to the appropriate Question object.

What I'm currently doing is giving each UITextField a unique tag, and then storing a pointer to each Question object in a dictionary with the tag values as the keys. Then when the appropriate UITextField delegate method fires, I look up the object in the dictionary through the UITextField tag.

This seems ugly to me, and I'm not too sure what happens if the UITableViewCell goes offscreen and is re-used elsewhere in the table. Is there a better way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, why not just use the UITextFieldDelegate protocol to tell the object that the text field has finished editing.

You'd simply do the following:
Make your Question a UITextFieldDelegate. Then define textFieldDidEndEditing in your Question implementation class

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    mAnswer = textField.text;
}
```

That should do it right? When the text field has finished, the Question object gets the answer.

Comment: Yep, this was the obvious answer that I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can figure out the indexpath of the cell and with that you should be able to get the corresponding object from the data model.

```
UITextField *someTextField;
UIView *contentView = [someTextField superView];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Roderick said, I'd be tempted to either:

Pass the object into the tableviewcell (have that tableviewcell set as the textfield delegate) and assign the value entered directly to the object in

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Or give each cell a unique identifier that relates to the object and in the same method

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

have it fire a notification with the entered value and unique identifier. Which you then catch and extract the value to be assigned to the object.

Comment: If you give each cell a unique identifier you lose the efficiency of the Reuse Queue right?

Comment: @Roderic in this case it should still keep the Reuse queue functionality. My thoughts were that you could use the tag property and set this to be the index of the data structure where the data structure is single level or create a property on a custom cell to hold a more detailed identifier. This identifier would then be updated to reflect the cell being shown to keeping the efficiency of the reuse queue and not coupling the individual cell into on data object.

Comment: Yes I suppose you'd still keep the efficiency of the ReuseQueue, but you'd lose the accuracy of the tags. Once a cell gets reused, the tag would then reference a different point. Unless I'm understanding the solution wrong.